# How can I convert my class-based view to function-based views? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to change all my class-based views to function-based views and I am having difficulty converting the following class:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['image', 'title', 'category', status', 'description']
    template_name = 'blog/post-form.html'
    success_message = 'Your post has been updated.'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Update post'
        context['submit'] = 'Update'
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        author = self.object.author 
        return reverse_lazy( 'profile', kwargs={'author': author.username})
```

The function and form should do exactly what this class-based view does, so if anyone can help me out, please let me know.

Comment: Why do you want to convert these to unction-based views in the first place? The idea of a CBV is to remove boilerplate code, such that one does not have to repeat themselves for standard tasks.

Comment: If you don't know how to get started, here is [a skeleton view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) that processes a form. Then, if you get stuck on a particular bit (e.g. doing the success message), you can post what you've written so far and get help for that specific part.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would like to customize the input widget for uploading the image and I can't seem to find a solution to do that when using a class-based view. That's basically the only reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [**`.form_class`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class) in an `UpdateView` (as well as in a `CreateView`). So we can create a form like:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['image', 'title', 'category', 'status', 'description']
        widgets = {
            'image': …
        }
```

Where you replace `…` with the widget you want to use for the `image` field.

Then you can plug in that form:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import PostForm

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'blog/post-form.html'
    success_message = 'Your post has been updated.'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Update post'
        context['submit'] = 'Update'
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        author = self.object.author 
        return reverse_lazy( 'profile', kwargs={'author': author.username})
```

Behind the curtains, if you do not specify a `form_class`, Django will simply make one for you with the [**`modelform_factory`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory), so by using another `ModelForm`, we do not change the logic of using the form.